# Spark ThriftServer failed to start in secured mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, kerberos

Configured Spark-1.4.1 and Hive-1.2.1 on a Hadoop-2.7.1 secured cluster with kerberos. Started external metastore with no sasl enabled. I can do basic operations in Hive server2 with beeline.

When trying to start Spark Thrift Server, getting exception something related to delegation token.

**Command**

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer --master yarn-client C:\Spark\lib\spark-core_2.10-1.4.0.jar
```

**Exception in Spark**

```
15/07/28 16:07:31 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Stopping DAGScheduler
15/07/28 16:07:31 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
15/07/28 16:07:31 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
15/07/28 16:07:31 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error stopping SparkContext after init error.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.close(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.stop(BlockManager.scala:1216)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1659)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:565)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLEnv$.init(SparkSQLEnv.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2$.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$Client$$obtainTokenForHiveMetastore(Client.scala:1162)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:263)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:561)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:497)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLEnv$.init(SparkSQLEnv.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2$.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.main(HiveThriftServer2.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$Client$$obtainTokenForHiveMetastore(Client.scala:1142)
... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:java.lang.NullPointerException)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getDelegationToken(Hive.java:2575)
... 23 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:java.lang.NullPointerException)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_delegation_token_result$get_delegation_token_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_delegation_token_result$get_delegation_token_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_delegation_token_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_delegation_token(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3293)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_delegation_token(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3279)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getDelegationToken(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1521)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:89)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getDelegationToken(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getDelegationToken(Hive.java:2572)
... 23 more
15/07/28 16:07:31 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
```

**Exception in Hive Logs**

```
2015-07-28 16:05:04,543 ERROR [pool-3-thread-5]: metastore.RetryingHMSHandler (RetryingHMSHandler.java:invoke(155)) - MetaException(message:java.lang.NullPointerException)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newMetaException(HiveMetaStore.java:5393)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_delegation_token(HiveMetaStore.java:5272)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.get_delegation_token(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$get_delegation_token.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:11488)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$get_delegation_token.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:11472)
at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:48)
at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.getDelegationToken(HiveMetaStore.java:5784)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_delegation_token(HiveMetaStore.java:5256)
... 15 more
```

Help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Spark-1.5.0. You can find the issue link below.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5111